# Applying multiple filters on Mongo collection in Meteor template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, collections, filter

I am trying to create a search function in Meteor. I am searching for items in a Mongo collection with specific attributes.

My filters are reactive variables like so:

```
this.canEnglish = new ReactiveVar(false);
this.canRussian = new ReactiveVar(false);
```

I am then trying to use these reactive variables as filters on a collection.

```
Template.Search.helpers({
profiles: ()=> {
    if(Template.instance().canEnglish.get()) {
        return Meteor.users.find({'profile.grammarskills': 'english'}); 
    } else if(Template.instance().canRussian.get()) {
        return Meteor.users.find({'profile.grammarskills': 'russian'});
    } else {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    }
}
});
```

The filters work like they should, but how can I apply multiple filters at the same time, for example in the code above return people that can both russian and english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers guys. Sorry if I was unclear in my intentions, but I wanted to get people that could both languages out of the database.
[Pankaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4925026/pankaj-jatav) was close, but I chose to solve the problem differently

```
var selector = [];
if(canEnglish) {selector.push('english');}
if(canRussian) {selector.push('russian');}

if(selector.length > 0) { 
    return Meteor.users.find({'profile.grammarskills': { $all: selector}}); 
} else { 
    return Meteor.users.find(); 
}
```

This way it becomes easy to expand with new languages

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to do this, you may either use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/) or [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) Mongo operator. I prefer using $or:

```
const selector = {
  $or: [],
};

if (canEnglish) {
  selector.$or.push({'profile.grammarskills': 'english'});
}

if (canRussian) {
  selector.$or.push({'profile.grammarskills': 'russian'});
}

return Meteor.users.find(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am adding both the condition. Please select according to your need.

```
1.//Atleast know one language.
if(canEnglish || canRussian) {
   return Meteor.users.find({$or:['profile.grammarskills': 'english','profile.grammarskills': 'russian']});

2.//Know both the language
} else if(canEnglish && canRussian) {
   return Meteor.users.find({'profile.grammarskills': 'english','profile.grammarskills': 'russian'});
}
```